# Saddle point of $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3x$

Tags: calculus

I know the critical points of $f(x,y)=x^3+y^3-3x$ are $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$.

I plotted its graph in Geogebra, and it seems $(1,0)$ and $(-1,0)$ are saddle points. Using Hessian, it's inconclusive.

For $(1,0)$, I took $\varepsilon>0$ and then
$$f(1+\varepsilon,0)=(1+\varepsilon)((1+\varepsilon)^2-3)$$
and since $\varepsilon$ is close to $0$, then
$$1+\varepsilon\cong1\Rightarrow(1+\varepsilon)^2-3\cong2<0$$
Therefore,
$$f(1+\varepsilon,0)<0$$

How am I supposed to take a point close to $(1,0)$ and show its image is positive and then, $(1,0)$ is a saddle point? I tried $f(1-\varepsilon,0)$ but it didn't work.

Comment: Leave $x$ fixed, and take small positive and negative values of $y$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need is to show that the difference
$$
f(x,y)-f(1,0)=x^3+y^3-3x+2
$$
takes both positive and negative values close to $(1,0)$. Just observe that
$$
f(1,\varepsilon)-f(1,0)=\varepsilon^3
$$
which is positive for $\varepsilon>0$ and negative for $\varepsilon<0$.

Answer (score 0):

You're not moving in alot of directions when you add an $\varepsilon$ to your $x$ coordinate. You're looking for "good" points in the $x$ direction, but you're free to move everywhere on the plane (don't keep $y=0$).

I would suggest you to write down $f(1+x', y) - f(1,0)$ as a function of $x'$ and $y$. Then look what are the force in action: what is positive, what can be made negative. Can the negative term be stronger than the positive terms ? If this is the case then will find natural candidates. Good luck !